# How to change icon on micro:bit LED matrix with input from serial port

Tags: python, pyserial, joystick, micropython, bbc-microbit

First of all, I am not a dev at all, just trying to make things working as I want. Cannot understand this:

From one side, this is my python script on Ubuntu PC which sending button inputs from Playstation 4 joystick to serial port of micro:bit (joystick is connected to Ubuntu via bluetooth):

```
import serial
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()

joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))

device = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)

try:
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 7:
                    device.write(b"1\r\n")
                elif event.button == 6:
                    device.write(b"2\r\n")
            elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
                if joystick.get_button(7) == 1:
                    device.write(b"1\r\n")
                elif joystick.get_button(6) == 1:
                    device.write(b"2\r\n")
                elif joystick.get_axis(0) < 0:
                    device.write(b"3\r\n")
                elif joystick.get_axis(0) > 0:
                    device.write(b"4\r\n")
                else:
                    device.write(b"5\r\n")
            if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
                if event.axis == 0:
                    if event.value < 0:
                        device.write(b"3\r\n")
                    elif event.value > 0:
                        device.write(b"4\r\n")
                    elif event.value == 0:
                        if joystick.get_button(7) == 1:
                            device.write(b"1\r\n")
                        elif joystick.get_button(6) == 1:
                            device.write(b"2\r\n")
                        else:
                            device.write(b"5\r\n")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("EXITING NOW")
    joystick.quit()
device.close()
```

From other side, this is the simple micropython code I flashed to micro:bit from Mu editor and expected it will work, but it doesn't  :lol:

```
from microbit import *

uart.init(baudrate=115200)

while True:
    joyinput = uart.read()
    if joyinput == "1":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_N)
    elif joyinput == "2":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_S)
    elif joyinput == "3":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_W)
    elif joyinput == "4":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_E)
    elif joyinput == "5":
        display.show(Image.HAPPY)
```

In REPL console of Mu editor, I can see that communication is going well, i.e. as far as I'm holding pressed some button or joystick axis moved, I'm getting REPL with appropriate number:

- 1 for joystick button 7 (R2)
- 2 for joystick button 6 (L2)
- 3 for joystick axis 0 left position (left analog on joystick)
- 3 for joystick axis 0 right position (left analog on joystick)
- 5 if nothing is pressed/moved

But icons on LED matrix never appear.

Till now, it was possible for me to display some icon, only if I add one more "else" statement at the end of script, but this is normal cause it is "else". 
E.g last two lines below:

```
from microbit import *

uart.init(baudrate=115200)

while True:
    joyinput = uart.read()
    if joyinput == "1":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_N)
    elif joyinput == "2":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_S)
    elif joyinput == "3":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_W)
    elif joyinput == "4":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_E)
    elif joyinput == "5":
        display.show(Image.HAPPY)
    else:
        display.show(Image.HAPPY)
```

[image]

Many thanks in advance, I would be glad to provide any additional info needed.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer on another site: https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8153 , so I would like to post it here, maybe it would be helpful for other people with same doubt. All credits goes to @jimmo on micropyhton forum, thanks also to @Iyassou who tried to help.

Below is mycropython code for micro:bit which will change icons on LED matrix (arrows in my case) according input from serial. Of course, you need to send these inputs somehow, I'm sending it with python script in post above and PS4 joystick.

```
from microbit import *

uart.init(baudrate=115200)

while True:
    joyinput = uart.readline()
    if not joyinput:
        continue
    joyinput = str(joyinput.strip(), 'utf-8')
    if joyinput == "1":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_N)
    elif joyinput == "2":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_S)
    elif joyinput == "3":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_W)
    elif joyinput == "4":
        display.show(Image.ARROW_E)
    elif joyinput == "5":
        display.show(Image.HAPPY)
```